How to display the current directory in VSCode Remote terminal prompt in Linux?
I am using VSCode Remote to connect to a Linux server, and my terminal prompt only shows a single $ symbol. I want the prompt to display the current directory as well. I have tried setting the PS1 variable in .bashrc, but it doesn't seem to work in the VSCode terminal. How can I modify the prompt in VSCode Remote to include the current directory?
I just open VSCode Remote and connnet to my server via ssh.
I try to open .bashrc through "source .bashrc" but raise an exception: "/bin/sh: 3: source: not found"
